# Burp Extender API : How to pick selected text on custom menu-item click

Tags: burp

I am building a Plugin.
I have created a Menu Item and i want to grab selected text when my menu item is clicked. Same like burp URL-decoder menu-item.

Regards.

Comment: When the menu is generated you get an IContextMenuInvocation object. This has methods to getSelectedMEssages and getSelectionBounds.

Comment: Thanks for you help :) 
But now i am thinking of how burp actually handle the updated selected string like i am using setRequest() method after updating selected string to make changes on editor but i lost the original request. 
Like if i use URL encode feature from burp menu bar and press Ctrl+Z then our changes revert back to original form but in my case Ctrl+Z not working as i am setting request with setRequest() method with updated content.
Do i need to implement my own Undo/Redo functionality here ???

Comment: Unfortunately, extensions can't modify the request and maintain the undo buffer. We may add this capability in future.

Comment: Thanks for your help and looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet using which i was able to get selected string

```
int[] selectedIndex = myburp.context.getSelectionBounds();
IHttpRequestResponse req = myburp.context.getSelectedMessages()[0];
byte[] request = req.getRequest();
byte[] param = new byte[selectedIndex[1]-selectedIndex[0]];
System.arraycopy(request, selectedIndex[0], param, 0, selectedIndex[1]-selectedIndex[0]);
String selectString = new String(param);
```